# Use PythonInterpreter in Java to remove file into recycle bin

Tags: python, java, pythoninterpreter

I want to use PythonInterpreter in Java code to remove file into recycle bin.

This is my Python code:

```py
from send2trash import send2trash

send2trash('C:\Slides\dog.jpg')
```

This is my Java code:

```java
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PythonInterpreter py = new PythonInterpreter();
        py.eval("from send2trash import send2trash");
        py.exec("send2trash('cat-2.jpg')");
    }
}
```

This is the error:

> Exception in thread "main" Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> NameError: name 'send2trash' is not defined

My Python code works correctly, but not in Java.

The Python environment is installed correctly because the Python code works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are supposed to execute line by line. Try instead to pass the whole string to `py.exec` :

```java
py.exec("from send2trash import send2trash \nsend2trash('cat-2.jpg')");
```

Comment: Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" SyntaxError: ("no viable alternative at input 'from'", ('<string>', 1, 0, 'from send2trash import send2trash\n'))

Comment: try `py.exec("import send2trash \nsend2trash.send2trash('cat-2.jpg')");` instead, maybe it does not support this syntax.

Comment: File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named send2trash

Comment: The problem now is that this module is not found. How did you install this package ? Where is it located ? You did not provide enough info about that, and it is actually another problem.

Comment: The actual path with which the code works in Visual Studio is:  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\send2trash\plat_win_legacy.py

Comment: Should I set up in my Intellij IDEA path for Python jdk?

Comment: I think you should look how to do it with PythonInterpreter, the docs may explain how. Otherwise, open another question here, because your original one ("I get this error while running the code") was solved, now you are encountering another one.